# Facing issue while updating job in AWS Glue Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am new to AWS Glue studio. I am trying to create a job involving multiple joins and custom code. Trying to read data from Glue catalog and writing the data into S3 bucket. It was working fine untill recently. I only increased more number of withColumn operations in custom transform block. Now when i try to save the job i am getting error as follows:

**Failed to update job
[gluestudio-service.us-east-2.amazonaws.com] updateDag: InternalFailure: null**

I tried cloning the job and doing changes on it. I also tried creating a new job from scratch.

Comment: Are you doing this with code or using the GUI interface?

Comment: I am doing it using GUI provided by glue studio.

Comment: I've got the same issue when trying to edit the job in the aws console glue studio. Did you find a solution to this?